In Django CI, githubactions try to another database for testing
This configuration refers to portfolio_db when running the server normally, and refers to test_portfolio_db during testing.
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "portfolio_db",
        "USER": "python",
        "PASSWORD": "python123",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "3306",
        "TEST": {"NAME": "test_portfolio_db"},
    }
}

However, when I actually run it through CI, for some reason it refers to portfolio_db. This is because githubactions assumes test_portfolio_db.
Does anyone know why it refarences at portfolio_db and how to properly run the test?
In addition, the test in the local environment passes
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/10016990263/job/27690629902?pr=42

CI is failing while running python manage.py migrate. The migrate command offers --database to specify the DB that you want to migrate. The actual tests are run in another step i.e. python manage.py test. These should automatically pick the test DB specified in your config above. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#test for more details.

I had created test_portfolio_db in advance, but it seems that migrate is not necessary in the first place. This is because test_portfolio_db is created in manage.py test. i'm trying to try
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/10019544641/job/27696205038

@Azeem san
thank you. An issue that has been going on for about a year has been resolved.
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/10019680997/job/27696499042

You're welcome! :) I just checked the latest commits on your repo. You may self-answer this in detail describing what exactly fixed it for you. All the best!

before:
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/10016990263/job/27690629902?pr=42
after:
https://github.com/duri0214/portfolio/actions/runs/10019680997/job/27696499042
I had created test_portfolio_db in advance, but it seems that migrate is not necessary in the first place. This is because test_portfolio_db is created in manage.py test.
In other words, the test passed after I removed the migrate command execution.
django's test command uses an existing migration file without creating one (it works locally because there are files that are ignored). If you have .ignore the migrations file, remove it.
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 1
      matrix:
        python-version: [ 3.12 ]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Set up
        run: |
          sudo systemctl start mysql
          mysql -u root -proot -e "CREATE USER 'python'@'localhost';"
          mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL ON test_portfolio_db.* TO 'python'@'localhost';"
          
          python -m pip install setuptools
          python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="$(base64 <<< "$RANDOM|TeStiNg|$RANDOM" | tr -d '\n')"
          python manage.py test

